# Comparing Local Instance and a Database schema

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I am not able to compare a instance of the database which is mapped locally with a SQL Server database schema. I tried with Tools->SQL Server->New Schema Comparison but it only compares two database schema.
Can anyone please suggest something on this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your issue is.  When I do this, it shows me all of the differences across all schemas.  Is this not what you need?  What version of VS are you using (version and edition)?

Comment: Do you mean you create a database project locally and check it in TFS, then create a schema in this database project, now you want to compare this schema with one in SQL Server?

Comment: I removed the mentions of TFS in this question, as TFS doesn't seem to have anything to do with the topic.